# $\overline{A \times B}=\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm being tasked with proving the following statement:
"Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces and $A \subseteq X$, $B \subseteq Y$. Show that $\overline{A \times B}=\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ where the first closure is taken in the product space."

This is what I have so far:

"$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$.
Then by definition, we have that $d_{X \times Y}((x,y), A \times B)=0$.
This gives us the following:
$d_{X \times Y}((x,y), A \times B)=0 \implies \max{\{d_X(x,A),d_Y(y,B)\}}=0$
$\implies d_X(x,A)=0, d_Y(y,B)=0$
$\implies x \in \overline{A}$, $y \in \overline{B}$.
$\implies (x,y) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$.
Thus, $\overline{A \times B} \subseteq \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$.
$(\Leftarrow)$ Now let $(x,y) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$.
Then we have that $x \in \overline{A}$ and $y \in \overline{B}$.
This means that $d_X(x,A)=0$ and $d_Y(y,B)=0$.
By definition of distance between a point and a set, then $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.
This means that $(x,y) \in A \times B$.
Since $A \times B \subseteq \overline{A \times B}$, then we must have that $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$.
Thus, $\overline{A} \times \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \times B}$.
And so, by double containment, we have that $\overline{A \times B}=\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, as was to be shown."

Let me know if I can change anything. Thanks!

Comment: I would consider adding the metric spaces tag to this question, since you're trying to prove the result in metric spaces and not in a general topological setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $\subseteq$ proof looks good.

Your $\supseteq$ proof doesn't work. Your error is believing that $d(x, A) = 0$ means $x\in A$. It does not. For instance, in $\Bbb R$ with the standard metric, the distance between $0$ and the interval $(0, 1)$ is $0$, yet $0\notin (0,1)$.

Instead, you know that $d(x, A) = 0$ and $d(y, B) =0$. What does this say about $d((x, y), A\times B)$? In other words, do what you did in the first part of the proof.

Comment: So $d(x,A)=0$ and $d(y,B)=0 \implies \max{\{d(x,A),d(y,B)\}}=0$, right? Do I just read the forwards direction backwards from this point?

Comment: @bzoll213 More or less, yeah.

Comment: I appreciate your help! :)